# TextBox, UserControl and formatting numbers

Tags: c#, xaml

I have this in my XAML:

```
<contr:Parameter
    TextBoxText="{Binding Cable.RHAn,Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DBL2Conv}, ConverterParameter=Angle}"
    LabelText="{Binding Units[Angle].Display}"
    DescrText="β=" />
```

And in the usercontrol XAML of Parameter I have this counterpart:

```
  <TextBox
        x:Name="ArrowTB"
        IsEnabled="False"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
        Width="auto"
        Text="{Binding ElementName=MyParameter, Path=TextBoxText}"/>
```

Now in the converter I try to format the number to be displayed with this format string: "##.#". However, I get "7.502" on my screen.
Debugging the converter shows me, that the formatting goes well.

What is going on here? Must I put the converter in the usercontrol somehow?

(the textbox is used for output only. That's why it is disabled)

Comment: Can you try the format as `0.00` instead?

Comment: Can you show your actual converter? You left out the interesting parts..

Comment: show the part where you convert number to string and how you assign it to text box then we can probably answer it.

Comment: Found it.  Yes you are right: the interesting part it not shown. And it is not the converter, but its use/not-use. I haave two overlaying canvasses and I used the converter in only one of them: the one overlayed. It's late already.... that's why.